# HIde header on scroll

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to have the header hide on scroll down and reappear on scroll up. Right now the header remains fixed regardless of scroll. I am also just beginning to learn.

https://jsfiddle.net/p17gfg2h/

Here is the JavaScript that I have tried to adapt to my code:

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.version'
]).
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);

// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
  didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
  if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
  }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();

  // Make sure they scroll more than delta
  if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
    return;

  // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
  // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
  if (st > lastScrollTop && st > headerHeight){
    // Scroll Down
    $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
  } else {
    // Scroll Up
    if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
      $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
    }
  }

  lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working [Demo](https://codepen.io/Humberd/pen/pbOLAw)

HTML:

```
<header class="" elastic-header>
    <ul>

    </ul>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
    background: #404040;
}

.hide-header {
    height: 0;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
(function() {
    angular.module("app", [])
        .controller("app.controller", function($scope) {

        })
        .directive("elasticHeader", function($window) {
            return {
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                    var lastPosition = 0;

                    $window.onscroll = function () {
                        var windowOffset = $window.pageYOffset;
                        if (lastPosition > windowOffset) {
                            elem.removeClass("hide-header");
                        } else if (lastPosition < windowOffset) {
                            if (!elem.hasClass("hide-header")) {
                                elem.addClass("hide-header");
                            }
                        }
                        lastPosition = windowOffset;
                    };
                }
            }
        })

})();
```

I created a directive called `elasticHeader` that I attach to the header in HTML. Because all the changes in the DOM should be done in the directives. Angular `$window` has the property `pageYOffset` and event `onscroll`, so whenever I scroll the page, the function attached to `$window.onscroll` triggers.

In that function I check if the previous last offset was greater than it is now. If it is, it will remove class `hide-header` that sets the `height` to 0. Otherwise I add this class. The css property `transition` does all the animation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wondering why your fiddle isn't working, remove the stric mode directive and set a stable version of AngularJS (where it says javascript with a little gear right next to it, under frameworks and extensions). Re-run it and it should work.